# Trouble Spawning Plantera

Tags: terraria-mobile

I'm having trouble with terraria. I can't spawn the Plantera. I want to know how you spawn him. Can someone tell me how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

According to the wiki article on [Plantera](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Plantera#Summoning) You summon him by breaking a [Plantera Bulb](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Plantera's_Bulb). These bulbs spawn in the jungle after you have defeated the mechanical bosses. They can be difficult to find as they spawn relatively slowly, but you can see them as a pink dot on the map. You just have to keep poking around the hardmode jungle until you find one.

Comment: The map trick is nice. Not sure if it works in 1.3, but I used to explore underground in pre-hardmode, and then when smashing altars, I found hardmode ores quickly. Same with plantera bulbs. You can hover over. I am uncertain if it still works though.